# Unable to retrieve OneDrive files shared with a user using Application Permission

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I'm working on a project which needs me to get onedrive files shared with a user. I'm using application permissions and have set all the required permissions and also consented according to the document on: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/drive-sharedwithme?view=graph-rest-1.0

I tried this get call:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{User-Principal-Name}/drive/sharedWithMe

But the response I'm getting is empty.

While using delegated permissions and with below get call:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/sharedWithMe

I'm able to list all the files shared with the user.

Am I missing out something here?
Any help will be welcomed!

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently supported, but the team is investigating making this work. Stay tuned!